# iPhone - Interface Orientation reversed?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ipad

Hi I have this piece of code...

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

and

```
- (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

  if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)){
    // WTF, this runs when I change to Landscape
  } else {
    // this runs when I change to Portrait??? shouldn't it be the contrary?
  }
}
```

as you see, the code is running in reverse, I mean, the part the should run when I change the device to portrait, the landscape part of the code runs and vice-versa.

WHen I turn the device, self.view rotates.

is this UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait testing how the interface is before the rotation or am I missing something?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that the method is named didRotate*From*InterfaceOrientation, so naturally the `interfaceOrientation` parameter contains the old orientation, not the new one.